# MDX - Create a Calculated Set From Union of Values in two sets

Tags: set, mdx

Let's say I have the following `MDX` Query:

```
Select 
    {measures.[Dollars]} on 0,
non empty 
[Divisions].[Division].[All].Children *
[Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[All].Children 
[Locations].[Locations].[All].Children 
on 1
From MyCube
```

which produced the following table:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Division</th><th>&nbsp;Cost Centre</th><th>&nbsp;Location</th><th>&nbsp;Dollars</th></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>1</td><td>X</td><td>$30.00 </td></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>1</td><td>X</td><td>$12.32 </td></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>1</td><td>X</td><td>$124.32 </td></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>1</td><td>Z</td><td>$64.24 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>1</td><td>Z</td><td>$63.13 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>1</td><td>Z</td><td>$84.23 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>2</td><td>Z</td><td>$254.37 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>2</td><td>Y</td><td>$27.23 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>2</td><td>Z</td><td>$12.01 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>2</td><td>Y</td><td>$12.42 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>2</td><td>Y</td><td>$53.26 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>1</td><td>Y</td><td>$76.26 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>1</td><td>Z</td><td>$63.74 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>1</td><td>Z</td><td>$2.74 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

What I am hoping to do is create a set out of the Union of specific values in the [Cost Centres].[Cost Centre] and [Locations].[Locations] hierarchies into a single set and use that new set in my MDX query across the columns.

Using the table and query from above, I have the following conditions that would determine the value in the set (lets call the new set 'NewSet'):

```
When Cost Centre = 1 and Location = X Then "CustomType1"
When Cost Centre = 1 and Location = Y Then "CustomType2"
When Cost Centre = 1 and Location = Z Then "CustomType3"
When Cost Centre = 2 and Location = Y Then "CustomType4"
When Cost Centre = 2 and Location = Z Then "CustomType5"
Else "Default"
```

Then, if I was to execute the new query:

```
with 
set NewSet as "Some Unknown Magic Here"
Select {measures.[Dollars]} on 0,
non empty 
[Divisions].[Division].[All].Children *
{NewSet}
on 1
From MyCube
```

I would end up with the following result:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Division</th><th>&nbsp;NewSet</th><th>Dollars</th></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>CustomType1 &nbsp;</td><td>$166.64 </td></tr><tr><td>AA</td><td>CustomType3&nbsp;</td><td>$64.24 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>CustomType3&nbsp;</td><td>$147.36 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>CustomType4</td><td>$27.23 </td></tr><tr><td>BB</td><td>CustomType5</td><td>$254.37 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>CustomType2</td><td>$76.26 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>CustomType3</td><td>$66.48 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>CustomType4</td><td>$65.68 </td></tr><tr><td>CC</td><td>CustomType5</td><td>$12.01 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: your table formatting is wrong: please can you add screenprints

Answer (score 0):

You just have a set of tuples of the members from each hierarchy that you're interested in:

```
SELECT 
  {measures.[Dollars]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Divisions].[Division].[All].Children*
  {
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[x]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[y]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[z]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[2], [Locations].[Locations].[y]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[2], [Locations].[Locations].[z])
  }      
 ON 1
FROM MyCube;
```

Or this can go in the `WITH` clause as in your question:

```
WITH SET [BLAH] AS
  {
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[x]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[y]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[1], [Locations].[Locations].[z]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[2], [Locations].[Locations].[y]),
    ([Cost Centres].[Cost Centre].[2], [Locations].[Locations].[z])
  }
SELECT 
  {measures.[Dollars]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Divisions].[Division].[All].Children*
      [BLAH]  
 ON 1
FROM MyCube;
```